# How can I create a large number of controls without blocking the Main Thread?

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading

Hi，guys， I don't understand how to handle the UI thread, so I try to create many UI elements in a child thread, but,
How to modify the following code so that the window don't block：

```
    public void CreateCtr(string name)
    {
        Button btn = new Button();
        btn.Content = name;
        btn.Width = 10;
        btn.Height = 10;
        content.Children.Add(btn);
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        int count = 100000;
        Task.Factory.StartNew(()=> {
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
            {
                this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(()=> {
                    CreateCtr(i.ToString());
                }));
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Seriously, why would anyone need a form with 100,000 buttons?!?

Comment: Actually,i just want to know whether or not have a way do that.

Comment: You can't create 100.000 buttons and it has nothing to do with time, it has everything to do with the fact that you won't be allowed to do it.

Comment: Now, if it was allowed then you still can't change your code so that it won't block, other than to periodically call `Application.DoEvents();` and that is simply because the creation of the control involves the UI and thus has to be done on the UI thread. If you're creating grids and filling them with data then you can put the "fetch and build the data to fill the grid with" job on a background thread but the "create the grid and fill it with the fetched data" has to be done on the UI thread.

Comment: Thanks for help,  when i set the first  parameter of function by this :Dispatcher.BeginInvoke( System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Background)  and the window doesn't block,why is this？

Answer (score 0):

You need to give the UI thread some space to breathe. With the current code, the UI thread is busy processing all the create button tasks and cannot get to processing user input. Put a minimal pause between creating each individual button. A few milliseconds are enough:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    int count = 100000;
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => {
                CreateCtr(i.ToString());
            }));
            Thread.Sleep(5);
        }
    });
}
```

The longer the pause, the more responsive the form becomes.

You will note that the form becomes less responsive again after some time, because after a certain amount of components on a form, adding another component takes very long. This is where my original comment becomes relevant: There is no usecase for having that many components on a form, so the framework is not designed to handle it well.

What might work is not putting all buttons on the same parent container but creating a tree of components where each component has no more than say 100 children. But again: I don't see any relevant usecase.

Comment: Q: while making an individual button is not a great task, would it work better to make an array of buttons not on the form, and then add them in bulk say 20/50/100 at a time?

Comment: @BugFinder I don't believe that this would improve performance but you are free to test it. :) What might work is not putting all buttons on the same parent container but creating a tree of components where each component has no more than say 100 children. But again: I don't see any relevant usecase

Answer (score 0):

Might work to disable the dispatcher when adding the controls.

```
int count = 100000;
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {
    using (var d = Dispatcher.DisableProcessing())
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(()=> {
                CreateCtr(i.ToString());
            }));
        }
    }
});
```